# replace blank value with previous first column value using awk and sed

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

```
john    math
        science
paul    math
        science
rosy    math
jill    science
rob     math
        science
hary    math
```

Desired output:

```
john    math
john    science
paul    math
paul    science
rosy    math
jill    science
rob     math
rob     science
hary    math
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `awk`, by acting upon number of fields

```
$ awk 'NF==1{print p "\t" $1; next} {p=$1} 1' ip.txt
john    math
john    science
paul    math
paul    science
rosy    math
jill    science
rob     math
rob     science
hary    math
```

- `{p=$1} 1` for lines other than single field, save first column and print the line
- `NF==1{print p "\t" $1; next}` if only one field is present, print previous field, `tab` and the field from input line. `next` will skip rest of statements and process next line

if `tab` separation doesn't work out, use `column`

```
$ awk 'NF==1{print p,$1; next} {p=$1} 1' ip.txt | column -t
john  math
john  science
paul  math
paul  science
rosy  math
jill  science
rob   math
rob   science
hary  math
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `sed` this way:

```
sed ':n; N; s/\n[^ ]/&/; tsplit; s/^\([^ ]* *\)\([^ ]*\n\) *\([^ ]*\)$/\1\2\1\3/; :split; h; s/\n.*$//; p; g; s/^.*\n//; bn' test.txt
```

#### Explanation

```
sed '# Start label for loop
:n
# Read next string to main buffer, separated by "\n"
N
# Split and print first string if second starts with non-space character
s/\n[^ ]/&/
tsplit
# "^\([^ ]* *\)" -- First word with spaces, \1.
# "\([^ ]*\n\)"  -- Second word, \2.
# " *"           -- Spaces in second line, throw them.
# "\([^ ]*\\)"   -- Second word in second line, \3.
s/^\([^ ]* *\)\([^ ]*\n\) *\([^ ]*\)$/\1\2\1\3/
# Splitting
:split
# Send both lines to hold buffer
h
# Delete second line, print first
s/\n.*$//
p
# Lines to main buffer, delete first.
g
s/^.*\n//
# Now second file is first, start loop again.
bn' test.txt
```